# get fiddler logs from a connection with selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, fiddler

my company have a bunch of websites that some of them redirect and some do not.
my job is to automate with selenium java to find which one is redirecting get  the fiddler log and send it to the advertiser responsible

i tried to find a way to get the log from the fiddler in an automated way
(.saz file or even text log) but i could not find any way to automate that

p.s.

if there's another way to get all the connections from a proxy server without fiddler it will be great too. but i need everything that the fiddler gets (the web view, the headers, the raw)

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler should be capturing all traffic.. and logs can be saved in an automated way...(you could also write custom rule if you have specific need).. I have done this before so i know it works

The log (saz or txt) has all required information. Different views by fiddler shows you  formatted and organized info...